# Modify Future Builder inside Stream Builder to avoid widget flickering

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a `FutureBuilder` inside a `StreamBuilder` that updates the UI every time a document is added to the `activity` collection, to get some aditional data from Firestore. The problem is that the `FutureBuilder` returns a `SizedBox` widget while the ConnectionState is waiting causing the all the cards to dissapear for a second. I would like to avoid this flickering since it causes a bad ui experience for users.

Is there a way to query the required user data in the activity stream so it all returns at once that way I can remove the `FutureBuilder`?

If not ... what would be a solution for this?

```
    activityStream() {
      return FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('activity')
          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
          .limit(55)
          .snapshots();
    }
```

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return const SizedBox(
                          height: 65.0,
                        );
                      }
```

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: activityStream(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        }

        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          default:
            final activityContent = snapshot.data?.docs
                .map((data) => ActivityModel.fromFirestore(data))
                .toList();

            return Scrollbar(
              controller: widget.scrollController,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                controller: widget.scrollController,
                itemCount: activityContent!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {

                  return FutureBuilder(
                    future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('users')
                        .where('uid', whereIn: activityContent[i].players)
                        .get(),

                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return const SizedBox(
                          height: 65.0,
                        );
                      }

                      final users = snapshot.data!.docs.map((e) {
                        return UserModel.fromFirestore(e);
                      }).toList();

                      return MyWidget(
                        users: users,
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
        }
      },
    );
```

Comment: "Is there a way to query the required user data in the activity stream so it all returns at once that way I can remove the FutureBuilder?" - sure, check https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#working-with-streams (or even better https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#modify-stream-methods)

Comment: If you want whole data of stream once, use get() method with firestore collection document along and await it. It will return you a future of data and you can handle your data accordingly.

Comment: Merging the stream with the futures takes too long ... Hope to find a solution to the version I have now. @pskink

Comment: I need to have a stream of data. I want it to update while users are using the app @K_Chandio

Comment: so try using  `async*` generator: https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#creating-a-stream-from-scratch and use `await for(final event in firebaseStream) { ...` for reading the original stream

Comment: I'm sorry ... but I don't know what you mean. I don't have too much experience with streams.